# Removing time series with only zero values from a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, time-series

I have a data frame with multiple time series identified by uniquer id's. I would like to remove any time series that have only 0 values.

The data frame looks as follows,

```
id   date          value
AAA  2010/01/01    9
AAA  2010/01/02    10
AAA  2010/01/03    8
AAA  2010/01/04    4
AAA  2010/01/05    12
B    2010/01/01    0
B    2010/01/02    0
B    2010/01/03    0
B    2010/01/04    0
B    2010/01/05    0
CCC  2010/01/01    45
CCC  2010/01/02    46
CCC  2010/01/03    0
CCC  2010/01/04    0
CCC  2010/01/05    40
```

I want any time series with only 0 values to be removed so that the data frame look as follows,

```
id   date          value
AAA  2010/01/01    9
AAA  2010/01/02    10
AAA  2010/01/03    8
AAA  2010/01/04    4
AAA  2010/01/05    12
CCC  2010/01/01    45
CCC  2010/01/02    46
CCC  2010/01/03    0
CCC  2010/01/04    0
CCC  2010/01/05    40
```

This is a follow up to a previous question that was answered with a really great solution using the [data.tables](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) package.

[R efficiently removing missing values from the start and end of multiple time series in 1 data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811357/r-efficiently-removing-missing-values-from-the-start-and-end-of-multiple-time-se)

Comment: Is the data frame ids always sorted?

Comment: @Fhnuzoag I sorted the data frame by id and date

Comment: If the data frame is sorted already, there's probably faster ways to do it than the ave method, then. But it's probably not worth it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `dat` is a `data.table`, then this is easy to write and read :

```
dat[,.SD[any(value!=0)],by=id]
```

`.SD` stands for Subset of Data.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508482/what-does-sd-stand-for-in-data-table-in-r) explains `.SD` very well.

Picking up on Gabor's nice use of `ave`, but without repeating the same variable name (`DF`) three times, which can be a source of typo bugs if you have a lot of long or similar variable names, try :

```
dat[ ave(value!=0,id,FUN=any) ]
```

The difference in speed between those two may be dependent on several factors including: i) number of groups ii) size of each group and iii) the number of columns in the real `dat`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Your data.table package is really useful. Going to make data wrangling a lot easier for myself.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. No packages are used.

```
DF[ ave(DF$value != 0, DF$id, FUN = any), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy  `plyr` solution would be

```
ddply(mydat,"id",function(x) if (all(x$value==0)) NULL else x)
```

(seems to work OK) but there may be a faster solution with `data.table` ...