# Data table, removing leading missing values by group

Tags: r, data.table

Below is an example data table, which I would like to remove the rows where value is NA and no earlier row has a value, i.e. also NA, and by group. As not all have the same number leading missing values I'm getting stuck and not having any luck searching.

Example data table

```
    group    date     value
      a 2015-01-01    NA
      a 2015-01-02     2
      a 2015-01-03     3
      a 2015-01-04    NA
      a 2015-01-05     2
      b 2015-01-01    NA
      b 2015-01-02    NA
      b 2015-01-03     2
      b 2015-01-04    NA
      b 2015-01-05     2
```

Finished data table

```
    group    date     value
      a 2015-01-02     2
      a 2015-01-03     3
      a 2015-01-04    NA
      a 2015-01-05     2
      b 2015-01-03     2
      b 2015-01-04    NA
      b 2015-01-05     2
```

Later I plan to impute the missing values by those that come before and after.

**EDIT:** Found previously asked question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811357/r-efficiently-removing-missing-values-from-the-start-and-end-of-multiple-time-se), which is similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A basic approach would be to use `which` and `.N`, like this:

```
DT[, .SD[(which(!is.na(value))[1]):.N], by = group]
##    group       date value
## 1:     a 2015-01-02     2
## 2:     a 2015-01-03     3
## 3:     a 2015-01-04    NA
## 4:     a 2015-01-05     2
## 5:     b 2015-01-03     2
## 6:     b 2015-01-04    NA
## 7:     b 2015-01-05     2
```

Comment: You could use `which.max` too, as it will take the first `TRUE` - save you needing to subset to `[1]`